Elliptic regularity for distributional right side and constant coefficients
There are many results concerning elliptic regularity and probably even more questions posted about it on here, but so far I was not able to find exactly what I need to know, so please forgive me if this was answered before in another thread.
In Folland's "Introduction to partial differential equations" Theorem 6.33 (p. 214) we have the following result:

Suppose $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ open, $L$ an elliptic operator of order $k$ with $C^\infty$-coefficients on $\Omega$. Let $u,f$ be distributions on $\Omega$ satisfying $Lu=f$. If $f\in H_{loc}^s(\Omega)$ for some $s\in\mathbb{R}$, then $u\in H_{loc}^{s+k}(\Omega)$.

As far as I understand it, this means $Lu=f$ holds in the distributional, i.e. weak, sense.
Now my question is the following: Is there a result like this for more general f? Like $f\in W^{s,q}(\Omega)$ for $s\in\mathbb{R}$ and $q>1$?
More precisely, in my setting I have stronger assumptions: $s=-2, n=1, q>2$. In addition, I have $\Omega$ bounded and open and $L$ is a quasilinear elliptic operator of order 4 with constant coefficients.
So I expect then that for a distributional solution of $Lu=f$ I would get that $u\in W^{-2+4,q}$ but I couldn't find any reference for such a result. Folland's Theorem 6.33 is the closest I found, but I need a little stronger result for the start of a bootstrap argument.
Any help or reference would be greatly appreciated.
